# What is the difference between duration().get(String) and duration().as(String)?

Tags: momentjs

The docs at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as/ seem unclear about this, the results differ (https://jsfiddle.net/andig2/b3xLzcu6/):

```
var d = moment.duration(1, 'year');
console.log(d.asMonths());
console.log(d.as('month'));
console.log(d.get('months'));
```

Returns 12,12,0 instead of 12,12,12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duration [`get`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/get/) docs says:

> As an alternate to `Duration#x()` getters, you can use `Duration#get('x')`.

So, you should refer to [`month`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/months/) that says:

> As with the other getters for durations, `moment.duration().months()` gets the months (0 - 11).
>
> `moment.duration().asMonths()` gets the length of the duration in months.

You duration is 1 year, so it has 0 months, the output of `get` is correct.

Maybe using [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-iso-string/) to show duration value will help to understand better the difference between `get` and `as`.